# Insert at a location in ArrayList c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, arraylist

```
ArrayList ArrAcc = new ArrayList(); 
string ArrValue = ClsContractAccount.GetAccount(LngContract, "R"); 
ArrAcc.Insert(1, ArrValue);
```

Getting a ArgumentOutOfRangeException when i try performing this query what is wrong in my execution?

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` instead of `List<>`?

Comment: i know that's an issue but the system i am transforming uses ArrayList so have to use that itself

Answer (score 5):

You must start with 0 index

```
ArrAcc.Insert(0, ArrValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` indices are 0-based, ... so you should use

```
ArrAcc.Insert(0, ArrValue);
```

.... or better

```
ArrAcc.Add(ArrValue);
```

By the way, .... you should use the [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) version of ArrayList: [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) (supported by .NET 2.0+).

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert into a position that isn't occupied.  You could just Add that item.

Comment: You can insert into a position that isn't occupied, but only one: the smallest index that doesn't already contain a value.  (In this case, 0.)

Answer (score 0):

Your index should be less than the Count and in C# everything is 0 based index. So, you should have `ArrAcc.Insert(0, ArrValue);`

Answer (score 0):

You must start from 0. You can use the following code:

```
        if (index <= arr.Count)
            arr.Insert(index, "something");
        else
            arr.Add("something");
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one of the ?arguments passed to the method is not null and does not contain a valid value.

To can use your code as follow:

```
ArrayList ArrAcc = new ArrayList(2) {"","" };
    string ArrValue = "Salam";
    ArrAcc.Insert(1, ArrValue)
```